# Could conditional vs could past simple

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions

In this paragraph is could used as past simple of can or it is used as conditional which mean roughly the same thing as "can"?

> Jack :" But they both happened on the day of the festival, right...?"
>
> Bob :"Just think about it, do you think *people* with a lot of enemies
>   here in this village **could** participate easily in a local festival?
>
> It *would* be especially hard for them to be around during the
>   festival.
>
> So they probably *left* the village intentionally around this time of
>   year to travel don't you think?".

Answer (score -1):

In the paragraph, *could* is conditional. Be careful: *can* and *could* can only be used interchangeably regarding formality (*Can we go?* vs *Could we go?*). Otherwise, they're different.

If you were to ask if people *can* participate, you're asking if they are able to do so.

On the other hand, if you were to ask if people *could* participate, you're asking if it would be possible for them to do so.

Comment: I meant when used as conditional they mean practically the same thing ( Could you do that ? / Can you do that ? / He could run miles / He can run miles

Comment: @VeryBadAtEnglish Sorry, I was editing while you commented. The edit should answer your question.

Comment: yes I just saw your edit, I have another question how do you know it is used as conditional and not as simple past ?  since we have "So they probably left the village"  they're talking about a past event. I'd like to be able to know the difference just from reading like you.

Comment: @VeryBadAtEnglish I think there are two factors that lead us to interpret "could" as conditional: 1) the use of "**a** local festival" (Bob is hypothesizing about people with a lot of local enemies not being able to take part in local festivals), and 2) the use of "would", which forms a pair with conditional "could": people in that situation couldn't possibly participate without being seen. So the conclusion is that they left.

Comment: @Gustavson Thanks - didn't quite know how to phrase it properly.

Comment: I see thanks for the answers I was analyzing the paragraph too and I noticed '  do you think people ' and not ' do you think those people ' which means he's talking generally ( hypothetically about people in general )

Comment: @VeryBadAtEnglish Exactly!